# How to properly activate an Anaconda environment when not using bash?

Tags: python, bash, shell, anaconda, tcsh

I have installed an additional Anaconda environment, running python 3.5, so that now I have:

```
# conda environments:
#
python3.5                 /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python3.5
root                  *   /Users/user/anaconda
```

The Anaconda documentation says that I need to do `source activate python3.5` to activate the new environment. What it does not mention is that `activate` only works in bash. I'm using tcsh, so that I currently have to switch to bash, issue the command above, and switch back to tcsh every time I open a new shell.

How can I ease this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to stay inside this shell, you need to replicate the logic that the activate script does for bash in your shell. I have found a gist that might work:
https://gist.github.com/mikecharles/f09486e884a0b41e1e8f

Comment: Thanks for this. The good thing about this is that I can just change the script to apply to my new Python version. But it seems to me that one should have an easier way to do this.